# Hibernate LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I am getting exceptions for my code which was working perfectly fine. An action method was to be called but, I get this exception just after the method invocation is done.

I tried all the options available on the web, but nothing seems to really help me.

```
12/14 23:30:17 INFO  er.SessionDetectionInterceptor  - as dualauth is disabled. session interceptor doesnt validate
12/14 23:30:22 ERROR te.LazyInitializationException  - failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.apalya.model.User.broadband, no session or session was closed
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.apalya.model.User.broadband, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:343)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.equals(PersistentSet.java:406)
    at java.util.Vector.indexOf(Vector.java:361)
    at java.util.Vector.contains(Vector.java:320)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:109)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:352)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:215)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:160)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:126)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:352)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:215)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:160)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:126)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:352)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:215)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:160)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:126)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:352)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:215)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:160)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:126)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.array(JSONWriter.java:441)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:150)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:126)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:352)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:215)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:160)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:126)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.write(JSONWriter.java:94)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONUtil.serialize(JSONUtil.java:115)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.createJSONString(JSONResult.java:200)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.execute(JSONResult.java:172)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:362)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:266)
    at com.apalya.filter.SessionDetectionInterceptor.intercept(SessionDetectionInterceptor.java:117)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.apalya.filter.UserDetectionInterceptor.intercept(UserDetectionInterceptor.java:53)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParameterFilterInterceptor.intercept(ParameterFilterInterceptor.java:135)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CreateSessionInterceptor.intercept(CreateSessionInterceptor.java:93)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.apalya.filter.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:29)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.apalya.model.User.broadband, no session or session was closed
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:230)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:160)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:126)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.write(JSONWriter.java:94)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONUtil.serialize(JSONUtil.java:115)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.createJSONString(JSONResult.java:200)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.execute(JSONResult.java:172)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:362)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:266)
    at com.apalya.filter.SessionDetectionInterceptor.intercept(SessionDetectionInterceptor.java:117)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.apalya.filter.UserDetectionInterceptor.intercept(UserDetectionInterceptor.java:53)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParameterFilterInterceptor.intercept(ParameterFilterInterceptor.java:135)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CreateSessionInterceptor.intercept(CreateSessionInterceptor.java:93)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.apalya.filter.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:29)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.apalya.model.User.broadband, no session or session was closed
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:230)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:160)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:126)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.array(JSONWriter.java:441)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:150)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:126)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:352)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:215)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.apalya.model.User.broadband, no session or session was closed
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:230)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:160)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:126)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:352)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:215)
    ... 93 more
Caused by: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.apalya.model.User.broadband, no session or session was closed
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:230)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:160)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:126)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:352)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:215)
    ... 97 more
Caused by: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.mypersonal.model.User.broadband, no session or session was closed
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:230)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:160)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:126)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:352)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:215)
    ... 101 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.mypersonal.model.User.broadband, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:343)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.equals(PersistentSet.java:406)
    at java.util.Vector.indexOf(Vector.java:361)
    at java.util.Vector.contains(Vector.java:320)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:109)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:352)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:215)
    ... 105 more
```

my model class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;

    private Boolean approved;
    private Boolean subscribed;
    private Date createdOn;

    private Set<UserBroadband> broadband;
    private Set<UserBussinessModel> userBussinessModel;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    @Column(name = "approved")
    public void setApproved(Boolean approved) {
        this.approved = approved;
    }

    public Boolean getApproved() {
        return approved;
    }

    @Column(name = "createdOn")
    public void setCreatedOn(Date createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    public Date getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }

    /*@OneToMany(targetEntity = com.apalya.model.UserBussinessModel.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "id")
    @JsonIgnore*/
    @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, mappedBy = "user"  )
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    @Basic( optional = false )
    @Column( nullable = false  )
    public Set<UserBussinessModel> getUserBussinessModel() {
        return userBussinessModel;
    }

    public void setUserBussinessModel(Set<UserBussinessModel> userBussinessModel) {
        this.userBussinessModel = userBussinessModel;
    }

    @Column(name = "company")
    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    @Column(name = "status")
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Column(name = "subscribed")
    public Boolean getSubscribed() {
        return subscribed;
    }

    public void setSubscribed(Boolean subscribed) {
        this.subscribed = subscribed;
    }

    @Column(name = "auto_provision")
    public Boolean getAutoProvision() {
        return autoProvision;
    }

    public void setAutoProvision(Boolean autoProvision) {
        this.autoProvision = autoProvision;
    }

    /**
     * @param fname the fname to set
     */
    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    /**
     * @return the fname
     */
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    /**
     * @param lname the lname to set
     */
    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    /**
     * @return the lname
     */
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    /**
     * @param lastLoggedOn the lastLoggedOn to set
     */
    public void setLastLoggedOn(Date lastLoggedOn) {
        this.lastLoggedOn = lastLoggedOn;
    }

    /**
     * @return the lastLoggedOn
     */
    public Date getLastLoggedOn() {
        return lastLoggedOn;
    }

    @Column(name = "from_date")
    public Date getFromDate() {
        return fromDate;
    }

    public void setFromDate(Date fromDate) {
        this.fromDate = fromDate;
    }
    @Column(name = "to_date")
    public Date getToDate() {
        return toDate;
    }

    public void setToDate(Date toDate) {
        this.toDate = toDate;
    }
    /*@OneToMany(targetEntity = com.apalya.model.UserBroadband.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "id")
    @JsonIgnore*/
    @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, mappedBy = "userId"  )
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
    @Basic( optional = false )
    @Column( nullable = false  )
    public Set<UserBroadband> getBroadband() {
        return broadband;
    }

    public void setBroadband(Set<UserBroadband> broadband) {
        this.broadband = broadband;
    }

}
```

Comment: you need to show the code.

Comment: I have added the model class, where I am getting the exception

Answer (score 4):

Lazy initialize exception happens when you have a relationship beetween objects, for example, ( one-to-many ) A client has lots of cars.
So what happens is that, you make a query, get a list of clients, then you CLOSE the session. After this, if you try to access the car Collection(that was not loaded) inside the client object you will get the Exception. You didnt post your code...this would help more.

EDIT:
And thats exactly what you exception is telling

> failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:
>   com.mypersonal.model.User.broadband, no session or session was closed

Comment: I have added the model class, where I am getting the exception

Answer (score 1):

You should either make eager fetch

`public Set<UserBroadband> getBroadband()` `@OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER`

or do your JSON serializing before session is closed.

When you are serializing your entity object after session is closed, it is not able to fetch lazy collection in that object.

Comment: I tried FetchType.Eager, then my jvm goes out of memory.
Can u explain me the second option, I have not tried the same

Comment: that means your set is really huge, and you should reconsider serializing it , as you have in comment consider @JsonIgnor ing it

Comment: There is more than one field lazy initialized, this will fail as well unless you serialize within your session, or change its fetch type.

Answer (score 1):

The first question one needs to ask is if they need the collections. If they need the collections then it is better to set it as EAGER loading.

If one does not need the collections then before the serialization process happens, set all the collections to null.

I got mine working by setting all the collections to null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to eagerly load the property "broadband" in User. Should be easy to fix. Hibernate loads collections lazily by default, do you just need to add fetch = FetchType.EAGER in the annotation or do the analogous thing in the xml.

Another option would be to invoke the broadband property while it is not yet detached from the session. For this you need to know where your transaction ends it your session is closed to do it before. Hibernate would then populate the field without throwing the error, because it still has access to the DB.

Understand that Hibernate does this for performance reasons. If you fetch everything in one query, you might end up fetching the entire DB (pizza effect).

Answer (score 0):

Duplicated of the following answered question:

You can use [HibernateFullPlugin](http://code.google.com/p/full-hibernate-plugin-for-struts2/) or this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269786/struts2-jsonresult-hibernate-lazyinitialization-how-to-deserialize-within-a-hi) implemented with an interceptor (same as HibernateFullPlugin but simplier).